# Modifying the forward function in llama2 model

Tags: pytorch, huggingface, large-language-model, llama

I want to create a smaller llama2 model. Particularly, I’d like to reduce the number of layers and add skip connections between specific layers. Can anyone help me to do this properly either in pytorch or hugginface format?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.